# i add to custom filed in category form for upload image but facing issue that i mention below

Tags: category, catalog

string
                    category
                    Menu Image
                    true
                    fileUploader
                    ui/form/element/uploader/uploader
                    Magento_Catalog/image-preview
                    false
                   40

```
    <field name="image_banner">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Banner Image</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
               <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="sunny_catalog/category_banner/upload"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

**Error**

> file-uploader.js:74 Uncaught TypeError: value.map is not a function
>       at UiClass.setInitialValue (file-uploader.js:74)
>       at UiClass.initialize (abstract.js:77)
>       at UiClass.initialize (wrapper.js:109)
>       at new UiClass (class.js:49)
>       at Object.initComponent (layout.js:137)
>       at fire (jquery.js:3232)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3362)
>       at Object.deferred.(/admin/catalog/category/index/key/5db0e6c2fed75d6118a879c215380e99c30f8d28c6a6d83414a674946b107297/anonymous
>   function)
>   (pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3461:37)
>       at fire (jquery.js:3232)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3362)

Answer (score 0):

You Need To Add Field In `Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\category_form.xml`

```
<fieldset name="general">
        <field name="your_attributte" sortOrder="40" formElement="fileUploader">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</elementTmpl>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Your Label</label>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <required>false</required>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <fileUploader>
                    <settings>
                        <required>false</required>
                        <uploaderConfig>
                            <param xsi:type="url" name="url" path="route_id/admin_controller_path/controller_file_name"/>
                        </uploaderConfig>
                        <previewTmpl>Magento_Catalog/image-preview</previewTmpl>
                    </settings>
                </fileUploader>
            </formElements>
        </field>
```

Comment: this not working i try it already once

Comment: any error generated for this code ?

Comment: yes same mentioned above

Comment: check uploader path